# OpenCV drawMatches function error (wrong source type)

Tags: python, opencv

When I try to do the following:

`cv2.drawMatches(img1, keypoints1, img2, keypoints2, matches, None, matchColor=(0,255,0), singlePointColor=(0, 0, 255))`

I get this error:

> error: OpenCV(4.1.0) ../modules/features2d/src/draw.cpp:127: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function 'void cv::_prepareImage(cv::InputArray, const cv::Mat&)'
>   Unsupported source image:
>       'src.type() == CV_8UC1 || src.type() == CV_8UC3 || src.type() == CV_8UC4'
>   where
>       'src.type()' is 21 (CV_32FC3)

This error wasn't occurring yesterday and I didn't update the environment or the images. How can I fix this error? Not sure how to properly convert it.

I can see that the error occurs from [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/1661e83939ff759e0697dcc67f4890dc6126c327/modules/features2d/src/draw.cpp#L127), but not sure what source type is expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function _prepareImage seems to accept CV_8UC1 this types is 8U: Unsigned int 8-bit, C1: 1 channels. However, it seems you're sending a 32F, so 32 bit, with 3 channels.

```
 where 'src.type()' is 21 (CV_32FC3)
```

Verify the type of the image you have and assign it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I simply had to convert the image types as follows:

```
cv2.drawMatches(np.uint8(img1), keypoints1, np.uint8(img2), 
    keypoints2, matches, None, matchColor=(0,255,0), singlePointColor=(0, 0, 255))
```